# list view context menu with list child item focusable android

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu, long-click

I have implemented an custom list view with base adapter that contains focusable item like button. so i have disabled the focusable and clickable in xml. My problem is , added context menu for list item in list view using register for context menu. how to make the list view respond for both long item click and also for button list item click?

Comment: Get reference to the button and then assign onclicklistener to it and also assign onlongitemclick listener to listview.hope this helps.

Comment: @SharadMhaske, u should post this as an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get reference to the button and then assign onclicklistener to it and also assign onlongitemclick listener to listview.hope this helps